# SQL Server : INNER JOIN returning incorrect row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables `Person` and `Table1`. I want to join the `person` table to `table1` where the `foodId` is 2.

However, when I do the inner join it is only joining the record where `foodId` is 1.

`Person`:

```
id      fName      lName
1       John       Smith
```

`Table1`:

```
id      personId      foodId     date
1       1             1          2014-10-28
2       1             2          2014-10-28
```

The query I tried is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Table1 t ON p.id = t.personId AND foodId = 2
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Table1 t ON p.id = t.personId 
WHERE t.foodId = 2
```

Both of those queries show empty results.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Either you're not really showing us your actual tables, or you're not showing us the correct data - with **this data** provided, query #2 **DOES** return `(1, 'John', 'Smith', 1, 2, '2014-10-28')` as its answer ....

Comment: That's what I thought it should return.  In my second query, if I didn't include that `WHERE` clause both records should be returned, correct?

Comment: The first query seems a bit odd in format. It might work if you try `INNER JOIN Table1 t ON p.id = t.personId AND t.foodId = 2` That might fix it, because your second condition doesn't reference a table alias. IF it works, it should still give the same result, though.

Comment: I got it working.  I had a typo in my second query in Sql Server, but typed it in correctly on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*SQLFiddle seems to be dead ... can't connect - therefore, posted here in all its glory...*)

Setup as shown in original question:

```
DECLARE @Person TABLE (id INT, fName VARCHAR(20), lName VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Person
        (id, fName, lName)
VALUES
        (1, -- id - int
         'John', -- fName - varchar(20)
         'Smith'  -- lName - varchar(50)
         )

DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (id INT, PersonId INT, FoodID INT, T1Date DATE)

INSERT INTO @Table1
        (id, PersonId, FoodID, T1Date)
VALUES
        (1, -- id - int
         1, -- PersonId - int
         1, -- FoodID - int
         '20141028'  -- T1Date - date
         ), (2, 1, 2, '20141027')
```

Query #2 shown in original question:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Person p
INNER JOIN @Table1 t ON p.id = t.personId 
WHERE t.foodId = 2
```

Output from that query:

[image]

There must be something else going on here - or you've oversimplified the setup to make it not work anymore. But your query #2 **DOES** return one row - the one you would expect.

Comment: I simplified the question, but I got it working.  In my join I was joining on `p.id = t.id` instead of `t.personId`.

Comment: @Andrew: **AHA!** - that wouldn't work, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need left join rather than inner join.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t LEFT JOIN Person p ON p.id = t.personId WHERE t.foodId = 2
```

Comment: Well, can you get right results when select * from each table?

Answer (score 0):

When you do Inner Join, only records which are present in both tables will be shown.

I love this picture
[image]